# Does TextView.getLayoutParams() have all the layout_align properties?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I have the following `TextView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayoutItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/linharegistro_par"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:minHeight="65dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblKg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblTroca"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblTroca"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/linharegistro_impar"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:text="Kg"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

That is inside a `RelativeLayout`, as you can see.

I am generating `Clone`'s of these elements, but to do a `Clone` you need to set all the element properties.

Here is the class of `Clone` that sets the properties:

```
public class Item {

    private RelativeLayout pnlItem;     
    private TextView lblKg;

    public Item(RelativeLayout pnlItem, TextView lblKg) {
        clone(pnlItem, lblIndice);
        this.pnlItem.addView(this.lblKg);                                       
    }

    public void clone(RelativeLayout pnlItem, TextView lblKg){

        this.pnlItem = new RelativeLayout(GruposForm.this);
        this.pnlItem.setLayoutParams(pnlItem.getLayoutParams());
        this.pnlItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.linharegistro_impar));
        this.pnlItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.pnlItem.setMinimumHeight(65);
        this.pnlItem.setPadding(pnlItem.getPaddingLeft(), pnlItem.getPaddingTop(), pnlItem.getPaddingRight(), pnlItem.getPaddingBottom());

        this.lblKg = new TextView(GruposForm.this);
        this.lblKg.setText(lblKg.getText()); 
         this.lblKg.setLayoutParams(lblKg.getLayoutParams());
        this.lblKg.setTextColor(lblKg.getTextColors());
        this.lblKg.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.linharegistro_impar));
        this.lblKg.setPadding(lblKg.getPaddingLeft(), lblKg.getPaddingTop(), lblKg.getPaddingRight(), lblKg.getPaddingBottom());
        this.lblKg.setGravity(lblKg.getGravity());

    }

}
```

In my code, I do the following to clone:

```
Item pnlItemClone = new Item(pnlItem, lblKg);
pnlContent.addView(pnlItemClone.pnlItem); //adding the cloned view to the main view.
```

declaration of `pnlContent`:

```
LinearLayout pnlContent = null;
```

association of `pnlContent`:

```
pnlContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutContent);
```

Don't worry about this `pnlContent`, it is just a LinearLayout that holds all the content of the `Activity` and it is working.

I want to know if the `this.lblKg.setLayoutParams(lblKg.getLayoutParams());` does set and get the following properties of my `TextView`:

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblTroca"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblTroca"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Im asking that because I see that the elements generated are getting misplaced on the `View` and I want to fix that.

`this.lblKg` is different from `lblKg`, `this.lblKg` is the new cloned `TextView` and `lblKg` is a private variable declared on the beginning of my `Activity` that is associated to the `TextView` that is inside the `XML Layout` here is the association:.

In the `onCreate` method:

```
lblKg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblKg);
```

At the beginning of my `Activity`:

```
TextView lblKg = null;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `this.lblKg.setLayoutParams(lblKg.getLayoutParams());` doesn't do anything. (how would it anyway ?)

Comment: why it does anything? `lblKg` is associated to my `TextView` that are declared on the `XML Layout`

Comment: is it? can you post the code where you do that ? (from that much code, lblKg and this.lblKg are the same object)

Comment: can you post **the code** where you do that ? (because from your explanation, they are still the same object)

Comment: so, they do are the same object. You need to declare another `TextView ` in your method. If you are not convinced, compare the instances for lblKg and this.lblKg.

Comment: nope, because i am inside a class named `Item`, wait i will post the whole code.

Comment: ok. I can't stress enough how using the same name for 2 variables is error prone, but nevertheless, this should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41607/discussion-between-paulo-roberto-and-njzk2)

Comment: what is `lblIndice` ?

Comment: sorry i mispeled that, its `lblKg` the right parameter. But in my code it is right i just typed it wrong on the question because i removed many elements of this clone to let you understand because little thing is better to see whats wrong.